# Windows Phone 8 - display text on tile

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, live-tile

I want to display text on a secondary tile, like Evernote. Currently, I use the FlipTileData because it supports text on the BackContent property. The problem with FlipTileData is, that I only need the back tile, not the front.

Is there a way to set content on the front or to create a tile which does not flip?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You start by creating a standard tile, then render a set of UI elements (eg. `TextBlock`) to an image to get the desired look, then set it as the 'BackgroundImage' of the tile.

The following tutorial and previous answer should help...

http://wp.qmatteoq.com/how-to-create-cool-custom-tiles-in-a-windows-phone-application/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9659172/247257

As the above links assume Windows Phone 7, you will need to [adjust the tile sizes for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202948%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Tilesizesandresolutions) and cater for the new *wide tile* size.

Comment: If I remove the tile from start, the images are still in the IsolatedStorage. Do I need to remove them manually?

Comment: Yes, if you generate an image for a tile, you should remove any un-needed images at a later date. You can use the [Windows Phone Power Tools](http://wptools.codeplex.com/) to look at the app on a device/emulator and see how many images it creates over time.